# How to display a huge image in Unity 2D scene?

Tags: unity, sprites, tiles, tilemap, mesh

I need to display a huge image (big like earth)  in a 2D scene,  it is a PNG format image of real world map. I think like the other map APPs, the map image should be loaded and displayed tiles by tiles, not the whole one at a time, but how to display them properly and efficiently? What I can think of is, generating serval `GameObjects` and set the tile images as `sprite` of `SpriteRenderer` to them. But is that stupid? I thought there should be more advanced way to achieve it. Could anyone give some advices? Very appreciate it!

Comment: how big? what's the image resolution. What's the largest proportion of the image that you will see at any one time. A tile based approach is a good call, especially if you can rig up a system to re-suse tiles 'objects' when the pan off screen.

Comment: In fact, the image will be boundless. Now I use 150 `GameObject`s and reuse them when camera movement, is that all right?

Comment: If it works, it works, I can't tell you otherwise. Difficult for me to make a judgement when I still have no idea what the scale of the image is, are we talking mega pixels or giga pixels of image? Is the image being cached from the hard drive in chunks, or do you load it the entire image into memory? Do you generate the this 'boundless' image procedurally, or is it from a file.

Comment: "I thought there should be more advanced way to achieve it." It's dangerous to look for "advanced" methods solely for the sake of being more "advanced." If a simple or even naïve method solves your problem, that's a good thing — simple code is usually easier to maintain, debug, and build upon than exotic hyper-optimized algorithms. Is there a specific problem you're experiencing with your simple method that's preventing you from getting the results you want? If so, ask how to solve that problem — it too might have a simple / non-"advanced" solution.